# Calculating the closest point inside an intersection of half-spaces

Tags: vectors, 3d

Is there an efficient way to calculate, given a point, the closest point to it that's on the inside of an intersection of half-spaces?

For example, given the half-spaces `a` & `b`, the closest point to `p` that's "inside" the half-spaces is `x`. `+`s denote which side is "inside" the half-spaces `a` and `b`.

```
.p
       ^
       |
       |
       | x
   <---.--------------> b
       |       +
       |
       | +
       |
       v a
```

I'm particularly interested in a method that works for half-spaces in 3D (planes).

My current line of thinking has me calculate the intersections between each combination of half-spaces, and then find the shortest point by picking from the shortest distance to each half-space and each intersection (line, point) that's also within all the half-spaces.

Is there a better way?

Comment: This is the classic problem underly much of *linear programming*.  Search that for the optimal algorithms.

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).